# boto's get_all_instances returns empty

Tags: boto

I'm trying to fetch all the running instances with boto hence:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_ec2(aws_access_key_id='...',aws_secret_access_key='...')
conn.get_all_instances();
```

but although I do have a running instance I get an empty list.

when raising debug to 2 I can see the below:

```
[DEBUG]:validating server certificate: hostname=ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, certificate hosts=['ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'ec2.amazon...
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Date: Sun, 16 Jun 2013 09:45:00 GMT
header: Server: AmazonEC2
2013-06-16 09:45:00,982 foo [DEBUG]:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DescribeInstancesResponse xmlns="http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-02-01/">
  <requestId>b30bbc2f-f553-419e-87db-6e453a3051f4</requestId>
  <reservationSet/>
</DescribeInstancesResponse>
```

thanks in advance everybody

Comment: Is it possible your instance is running in a region other than us-east-1?

Comment: it runs at us-east-1d how do I point boto to thwre?

Comment: From the debug log above, I can see that you are hitting the us-east-1 region of EC2 and, therefore, any server running in any availability zone would show up.  And yet no servers instances are being returned by EC2.  So, if you are talking to the right region, the only other thing I can think of is that you are using different credentials when you are calling the get_all_instances than you are when you created the instance.

Comment: boto (and bintools) is only able to list instanced (and AMIs) that where created by api (boto/bash-bintools, etc.) but not ones created by the console.

however, the console was able to list everything no matter how it was created.
looks like a bug in EC2 to me

Comment: No, boto will list all instances running under the current credentials in a given region.  Doesn't matter if they were started with the console, boto, or some other tool.  It's is not a bug in EC2.  The only explanation is that the access_key/secret_key you are providing boto is different than the ones you are using in the console.

Comment: I don't think there's a credentials conflict. if there was one I shouldn't be able to see the boto-started instances from the console (this would be a security breach). I see the ec2 empty response, it's defenetively not bot's fault (and the same happens for bash-bintools). that's probably an aws bug. I moved to rackspace which is much simpler to understand and needs nothing complicated like boto, curl is enough for it

Comment: It's not an AWS bug but glad you are unstuck now.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to get the current running instances in a region

```
import boto.ec2
ec2_connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region, aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
instances = ec2_connection.get_only_instances(filters={'instance-state-name': 'running'})
```

This will return a list of boto.ec2.instance.Instance

[boto API documentation - get_only_instances](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_only_instances)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, it is best to specify the region you wanted to connect instead of relying on the default which is us-east-1. Try this:

```
>>> import boto
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> region = boto.ec2.get_region('us-west-1', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
>>> print region
RegionInfo:us-west-1
>>> conn = boto.connect_ec2(aws_access_key_id=access_key,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region=region)
>>> conn.get_all_instances()
[Reservation:r-xxxx, Reservation:r-xxxx]
```